# Counting the elements in a Hamming sphere using Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, coding-theory, spheres

We have the following Hamming sphere

$$\mathcal B_3= ((0,0,0,0),(\mathbb F_7)^4)$$

with $\mathbb F_7=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

So we want to know all possible elements with Hamming distance $\le3$ to $(0,0,0,0)$

$$\{u\in\mathbb F^4_7:dist((0,0,0,0),u)\le3\}$$

It is obvious that we have to use combinatorics to solve this problem.

First we notice that three elements in u have to be $\neq 0$

$$u=(v1,v2,v3,0) \ v_i \neq 0 $$

to get the Hamming distance of $3$.

The next step would be to count all the possible combinations to choose $3$ positions of a vector with length $4$.

$$ \frac {4!}{(4-1)!\cdot1!}=24$$

We know that $v_1,v_2,v_3\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

So for each $v_i$ we have $6$ possible combinations. How do I combine this with the $24$ from above?

Comment: As @satishramanathan pointed out, you incorrectly calculated $\binom{4}{3} = 4$ as $24$.

Answer (score 4):

A Hint: The question was about words at Hamming distance $\le 3$, but you seem to have concentrated on those at distance exactly $3$. But the maximum distance in this space is $4$. So you can simply

- Observe that there are $6^4=1296$ words at distance exactly four from $(0,0,0,0)$.
- Then observe that the total number of words in this space is $7^4=2401$.
- That leaves $2401-1296=1105$ vectors that are at distance $\le3$.

Comment: If we want the Hamming distance of 4, then all $v_i\neq 0$ in $(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$. And how do I calculate the amount of these vectors?

Comment: With the amount of all words with Hamming distance 4, we can subtract this number from $7^4$ which are all words in $(\mathbb F_7)^4)$ Am I right?

Comment: Correct @Anil ! To answer the first question: there are six choices for each of the $v_i, i=1,2,3,4$. This time no worries about placing the zeros because there aren't any! So....do the same you did for the case of seven choices per component.

Comment: Does that mean that I have to multiply 6 4 times? $6^4=1296$ or use some specific Combinatoric formula @Jyrki ?

Comment: Did you have to use something specific when you calculated the total number of vectors to be $7^4$ :-)

Comment: Alright thank you, you helped me a lot. I just thought that I have to use combinatorics on this task. $7^4-6^4=1105$ will me give the answer

Comment: In combinatorics there are often many routes to the destination :-) From satish's answer you can count that there are $\binom 436^3=864$ words at distance exactly three. Similarly there are $\binom 426^2=216$ words at distance exactly two and $\binom 416^1=24$ words at distance one. Finally, the zero word is at distance zero, $1$ word. Total:
$$1+24+216+864=1105.$$ But, it was easier to arrive at the $1105$ figure via this alternative route, no?

Comment: @Anil Sorry about being a bit finicky with the details. I really wanted you to figure this out yourself. Good job!

Comment: Thank you, but sometimes maths can be quite challenging. But your hints were very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If what you say is true about hamming distance, then it is $4*6^3$  It is not 24 but 4

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/825296)

Comment: I am not critiquing or requesting clarification.  It just provides answer for the question that the OP has asked.  "  How do I combine this with the 24 from above?"

Comment: A one-line response rarely makes a good Answer, in part because the terseness of such replies leaves the Readers with much guesswork about what the pronouns used are meant to reference.  If you are critiquing the Question itself, a Comment would be sufficient to say the little you've said here.  If you want to give a complete Answer, be more verbose.

Comment: Correct, but you have not counted the words at Hamming distance strictly less than 3. The OP suffers from the same malady.